# Possible sides of and octahedron

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

What number of unique patterns can be made if all sides of an equilateral octahedron is blue or green? How do you solve such a problem?

I have only tried to solve this by a hands-on approach, i.e. actually painting the sides of an octahedron and making notes. I would like to find a mathematical approach.

Background: I lay in my bed, came up with this problem and now I am trying to understand how to solve it with the help of mathematics. That's all the background there is. I have no tools. Please don't kill my curiosity for math as an adult. Teachers already did a great job when I was a student.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to solve this by actually mark the sides of an octahedron and by making notes. Got an answer, but I'm not convinced it's correct. Shouldn't there be a math formula for this problem?

Comment: In principle there are $2^8$, but in reality there are less because of *symmetries* of th eoctahedron. One needs the symmetry group of th eoctahedron and all its subgroups and can then work with inclusion-exclusion

Comment: Cross reference: [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/579733/35416) seems related.

Comment: Why not instead give an example on how to write the question, in line with how you operate here Jyrki Lahtonen? Nice way to meet new members.

Comment: So what do you know about symmetry groups? The answers I could come up will rely on them heavily, so they will be all Greek to you unless you know basics. You see, there is a REASON why we insist on getting some context that only you can provide :-)

Comment: Let me coin this term for you: "math-idiot" (that's me). I know nothing about symmetry groups, even less about how to tackle a problem like this. As you probably can deduce from my question and answers, I have little previous knowledge. Thought that this would be a perfect place to find brilliant people who can teach me how to solve problems like these, with really smart mathematical concepts and approaches and beautiful enough so that basically anyone without math background, but with interest, can understand. If you know of a better place, please tip me. :-)

Comment: Sorry, about coming hard on you at first. I think that you will find the bits about symmetries and symmetry groups interesting. That Wiki-article is a good starting point, but may not be enough to allow you to follow this (or Marko's answer to your other question).

Comment: @ValX: Can you see that the twice-edited version of your question is *far* better than the original? (+1 from me!) Giving us an idea about what you know (or don't know) about the problem, and the means by which you've come across it, helps us provide answers that fit your experience level. (Also, without the added context, we'd never know you're a motivated self-learner and not a do-my-homework-for-me student. You can probably understand that people are generally more inclined to help the former than the latter.) Good luck with your self-studies.

Answer (score 4):

Let's agree to call two colorings equivalent if they can be gotten from each other by rotating the octahedron (we could also allow reflections, but those involve breaking the octahedron to atoms, so I'm not).

There are $24$ rotational symmetries: you can rotate a given vertex to any of the $6$ positions. Also, leaving a given vertex were it is, we can still rotate the octahedron by any multiple of $90^\circ$ about the axis formed by that vertex and the one opposite.

$24$ rotations fall into following types (called conjugacy classes):

1. the identity rotation (= do nothing).
2. $3$ rotations by $180^\circ$ about one of $3$ axes joining a pair of opposite vertices, such rotations interchange $4$ pairs of faces with each other.
3. $6$ rotations by $90^\circ$ about the same axes. Any one of these permutes
   two sets of $4$ faces cyclically amongst themselves.
4. $8$ rotations by $120^\circ$ about an axis joining the centroids of two opposite faces ($4$ choices for the two faces, two choices for the direction of rotation). Any one of these maps the face intersected by the axis to itself, and cyclically permutes the remaining six faces in two sets of three.
5. $6$ rotations by $180^\circ$ about the axis gotten by joining the midpoints of two opposite edges of the octahedron. These too swap the faces in four pairs.

To use [Burnside's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) we consider all possible colorings, and count the number of colorings fixed by that rotation. Observe that a rotation fixes a coloring if and only if the faces mapped to each other by that rotations share the same color.

1. The identity rotation fixes all $2^8=256$ colorings.
2. Rotations by $180^\circ$ acted on the faces as four pairs. We can select either color to each pair, so there are $2^4=16$ colorings fixed by any of these.
3. Here the two sets of four faces must both be unicolored, so the $90^\circ$ rotations fix only $2^2=4$ colorings.
4. For the $120^\circ$ rotations we can make four independent coloring choices: one for both fixed faces, and one for the two triplets. A total of $2^4=16$ colorings are fixed by these rotations.
5. This is the same as in case 2. above.

Burnside's lemma then tells us that the number of indistuinghisable colorings is
$$
\frac1{24}(256+3\cdot16+6\cdot4+8\cdot16+6\cdot16)=23.
$$

Comment: I'm afraid this may be difficult to follow. Do study that Wikipedia-article first. The group of rotational symmetries is the same for the octahedron as it is for the cube.

Comment: Hm, I think I pretty much follow. The scary part here is to trust mathematics. When I try to solve this problem practically (using pen and paper), I come up with 21 unique patterns. Would a different mathematical approach render in any other plausible output than 23?

Comment: If we allow reflections, too, then the number should go down a bit. 1:30 am here now, so I will leave that for tomorrow (unless somebody else kindly obliges).

Comment: This is so inspiring. Never would've thought of anything like this. It's like you are turning on completely dead parts of my brain. Jyrki, could you have a look at my other two unanswered questions?

Answer (score 2):

Coloring the faces of an octahedron is the same as coloring the corners of a cube; the latter is probably easier to picture.

No blue corners is one configuration (call it $0.1$).  One blue corner is one configuration $(1.1)$.  Two blue corners: either the two are on the same edge $(2.1)$, or they're opposite corners on the same face $(2.2)$, or they're diametrically opposite $(2.3)$.  Three blue corners: either all three are on a single face $(3.1)$, or two are on the same edge and the third is on the opposite edge $(3.2)$, or no two are on the same edge $(3.3)$.  That's $8$ configurations so far.  There are $8$ more that come from swapping blues and greens to yield from five to eight blue corners.

Finally, four blue corners.  All four can be on the same face $(4.1)$.  Three can be on the same face, with the fourth on the opposite face; if those three make an L-shape on the front face, the fourth can be in four different positions on the back face $(4.2-4.5)$.  Two can be on one edge with two on the opposite edge $(4.6)$.  Or no two can share an edge $(4.7)$.  Putting these together:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{# blue} & \text{# colorings} \\
\hline
\;0 & \;1 \\
\;1 & \;1 \\
\;2 & \;3 \\
\;3 & \;3 \\
\;4 & \;7 \\
\;5 & \;3 \\
\;6 & \;3 \\
\;7 & \;1 \\
\;8 & \;1 \\
\hline \text{total} & 23
\\ \end{array}$$
If you do not count reflections as distinct, then two of the four ways of making an L-shape on the front face and placing the fourth blue corner on the back face are equivalent.  The total number of configurations would then be $22$.

Comment: Note that the entire answer can be kept in terms of an octahedron by switching the terms "face" and "corner" throughout.